# Enable index without rebuild?

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server 2012 Entreprise.

I have a table of 12 billion rows that takes 700GB on disk, in 30 partitions.
It has only one index, clustered.
I have 500 GB free disk space.

I disabled the index (please don't ask why. If you have to know, I targeted the wrong database).

I now want to enable the index. If I do

```
alter index x1 on t1 rebuild
```

I eventually get an error because there is not enough free disk space. That was a painful lesson about disk space requirements for rebuilding a clustered index.

Ideally, I want to rebuild the index one partition at a time. If I do

```
alter index x1 on t1 rebuild partition = 1
```

I get the error: Cannot perform the specified operation on disabled index.

Any solution, besides buying more physical disks? The table has not changed since disabling the index (can't be accessed anyway), so I am really looking for a hack that can fool SQL into thinking the index is enabled. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If its a clustered index that you have disabled you have effectively disabled the table the only operations you can execute on this table is "drop" or "rebuild" as far as i am aware.

you could try the deprecated dbbc dbreindex command, maybe you are lucky and it rebuilds more disk space efficiently. Also you might squeeze some more space out if you set a fill factor to 100 when you rebuild. assuming you database table is now only being read.

```
DBCC DBREINDEX ('Person.Address', 'PK_Address_AddressID', 100)
```

allows you to reindex just the clustered index.

Comment: I plugged a USB drive, added some tempdb files and ran Alter Index Rebuild, so did not have the opportunity to try DbReindex. Thanks